# Difference between super() and {parent_class_name} in case of update class property

Tags: python, inheritance, class-properties

I've wrote the following code to explain what I've found using super(). :

With Parent.set_prop():

```
class Parent:
    parent_prop = None

    @classmethod
    def set_prop(cls, value):
        cls.parent_prop = value


class Child1(Parent):
    @classmethod
    def set_prop(cls, value):
        print("Child1 set parent prop")
        Parent.set_prop(value)


class Child2(Parent):
    pass


cls1 = Child1()
cls2 = Child2()
cls1.set_prop(10)

print(cls1.parent_prop)
print(cls2.parent_prop)
```

With super().set_prop()

```
class Parent:
    parent_prop = None

    @classmethod
    def set_prop(cls, value):
        cls.parent_prop = value


class Child1(Parent):
    @classmethod
    def set_prop(cls, value):
        print("Child1 set parent prop")
        super().set_prop(value)


class Child2(Parent):
    pass


cls1 = Child1()
cls2 = Child2()
cls1.set_prop(10)

print(cls1.parent_prop)
print(cls2.parent_prop)
```

The result of the first execution is:

```
Child1 set parent prop
10
10
```

The result of the second execution is:

```
Child1 set parent prop
10
None
```

I didn't expect any differences between both. Why calling the set_prop method with super() doesn't set the value for all instances of the class?

Comment: Can you show the actual code instead of the vague description *"If the Base.setUpClass() in test class 1 is replaced with super().setUpClass()"*?

Comment: "The result of the execution is" Result of executing *what*? The code only defines classes, it never actually instantiates them or calls their methods.

Comment: FWIW, filling in some blanks I *think* the issue is that ``cls`` differs when the classmethod is called on ``super()`` vs ``Base`` – which is somewhat to be expected but admittedly not exactly obvious. If that is the case, you might want to seriously cut down the example – a ``classmethod`` that just ``print(cls)`` and two child classes calling the classmethod via ``__init__`` should suffice.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - first of all the example is with unittest and if you use it as a runner that will be the result. For the second comment - may be this is the case , but can you explain that behavior in details?

Comment: I've updated the example. I hope it's a way clear now.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is obvious when you add a `print(cls)` to `Parent.set_prop` :

```py
    @classmethod
    def set_prop(cls, value):
        print(cls)
        cls.parent_prop = value
```

When ran in case 1 :

```
Child1 set parent prop
<class '__main__.Parent'>
10
10
```

When ran in case 2 :

```
Child1 set parent prop
<class '__main__.Child1'>
10
None
```

That's because [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) does not give you the parent class, but a proxy which will call the parent's methods (using a special `__getitem__`) but with the same parameters, here the same value for `cls` which is `Child1` in the second case, but simply `Parent` in the first case.